# can't set french characters from java program in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, database

I want to add a few french sentences in a db.
I do this from a java program linked with my db.

Everything works fine except when I use this token '.

From then I get an error: 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'allié de vos biceps.  Résiste à une charge maxi de 160kg. S'utilise avec les dis' at line 1

this is the text i want to add in the db:
Conçu pour la musculation des bras : biceps et triceps. Barre filetée pour sécuriser votre pratique. **L'allié de vos biceps.  Résiste à une charge maxi de 160kg. S'utilise avec les disques diamètre 28mm. Poids de la barre 6.5kg.**

can somebody help?

Comment: It doesn't look like a problem with accented characters, but with a single-quote character not being escaped.

Comment: Didn't sanitize your input. Helps if you provide code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use prepared statements. You're creating wrong syntax by not doing so. Your code looks now like this:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO ... ('" + input + "');";
```

But if input contains a `'`, you create a query like this for example:

```
INSERT INTO ... VALUES ('L'allié vos');
```

which is of course not good. To fix this, take a look into Prepared Statements, simply Google it.